# how to Get the value of asp checklist box in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

hi i am using this code for getting the value but it show only text instead of value please help me... 
my checkbox list is:

```
  <asp:CheckBoxList  ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" onchange=" GetSelectedItem();">
                     <asp:ListItem  Text ="Show only Refundable  Fares"  Value ="false"  ></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text ="helloe" Value ="true" ></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text ="" Value ="" ></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

my javascript code is :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedItem() {

        var CHK = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID%>");
      //  var CHK = document.getElementById("CheckBoxList1").;

        var checkbox = CHK.getElementsByTagName("input");
       var label = CHK.getElementsByTagName("label");
       var refund = new Array();
       var values = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
            if (checkbox[i].checked) {

            refund[i] = label[i].innerText;

             alert("Selected = " + refund);

            }
        }
        $('#hdnrefund').val(refund);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
label[i].innerText;
```

to

```
label[i].value;
```